# Algorithm for sorting graph nodes to increase cache locality

Tags: sorting, caching, graph

I have a directed acyclic graph with millions of nodes. The graph is split up in dependency layers, so that the nodes of layer n is only linked to by nodes from layers 1 to n-1.

The value of each node is calculated from incoming nodes. The value stored in a node is small, say maximum 8 bits.

[image]

When the values at layer 0 of the graph chance, the whole graph is recalculated in stages, from left to right.

For each layer, the nodes are recalculated in index order: first node 5, then node 6 etc.

As you can see in the graph above, node 5 is dependent on nodes 0, 1, 2, and 4. Similarly, node 9 depends on values 0, 1, 3, and 4.

For cache locality, it would be much better to change the index of node 9 to 6, so that the values stored in 0, 1, and 4, used by node 5, are still warm in the cache when node 6 is calculated.

Of course, swapping the positions of nodes 9 and 6 may result in a less optimal pattern for what was originally node 6.

What I'm looking for is for suggestions on algorithms to sort my graph for improved cache locality.

Notes:

- Recalculation a node is extremely cheap. The whole operation is entirely memory access limited.
- The graph is very sparse. Each node will usually have a fanout of only a few other nodes.
- Assume that most nodes will change their value during an update cycle and that there is no benefit in checking first whether or not the input values of a node have changed.
- The organization of the graph as illustrated is such that it can easily be parallelized for GPU. That's also why the graph is updated in layers.

Comment: "swapping the positions of nodes 9 and 6 may result in a less optimal pattern" Without any specific information on this, designing an algorithm to prevent or balance this loss of optimality is impossible.

Comment: I've added some notes about the cost of updating a single node (trivial) and the fact that it should be easy to run this on a parallel processor such as a GPU.